# Cast some elements of std::array to shorter std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

Is it possible to cast last 3 elements of 
`std::array<double, 4>`
to 
`std::array<double, 3>`?

For example:

```
void f(std::array<double,3> &);
...
int main() {
    std::array<double,4> a;
    ...
    f(/* pass a[1], a[2] and a[3] */);
}
```

EDIT:

Context:
There are couple of lattice spin (point) properties that are computed by different functions (different f()-s). 
Those functions should populate different parts of the array. 
(Array cannot be structure because number elements depends on compile-time arguments.)
Those f()-s are called millions of times.

Comment: Make your function take two iterators.

Comment: Yep, +1 to that. Ranges in C++ are supposed to be passed using iterators.

Comment: @chris Time critical application. I need it in compile time.

Comment: @Predrag, If creating a temporary in that unscalable manner, or using iterators isn't good enough, I fear you might have to make your own class that can do what you want. Just be sure it's really buying you time, though.

Comment: @Predrag I think you’re confusing something here. Passing iterators doesn’r generally incur a runtime overhead.

Comment: If you need to do such subarrays as arrays, maybe you should use `valarray` instead of `array`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph but iterating through array does.

Comment: @Predrag, What exactly are you doing with it that's so much faster with a `std::array`?

Comment: @chris It is crystal lattice simulation. It takes a lot of time and couple of percents make a difference.

Comment: I hopped for some template meta-programming magic.

Comment: @Predrag, I can at least say to profile both ways, but nothing is going to actually extract the three values without making copies. I suppose you could move them into the new array. That shouldn't really be your primary concern, though, it seems.

Comment: I'm looking for no run-time overhead solution. Just compiler to look at last n values as another (shorter) array.

Comment: @Predrag No, it does *not*. Why would iterating through an array be faster than through iterators? I’m not sure what you mean but I’m almost sure that what you think is wrong.

Comment: "NO! Don't give me solutions! Give me magic!"

Comment: @KonradRudolph Because I'm not iterating. I have meta code that generates code that accesses elements directly.

Comment: @Predrag describe your problem properly and you might get appropriate solutions. As it stands currently, your question contains a description of the solution you tried for your problem, but it has no description of the problem.

Comment: Added some context description.

Comment: It still sounds like a job for iterators...

Comment: In any case indices if doesn't want to move or copy.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I know that in 99.9% of situations iteration overhead is negligible. But in this particular situation it is not. I really need a cast (or some other compile-time feature).

Comment: @Predrag No, you don't. There's no iteration overhead. Stop spewing FUD and go back to work writing a fast, maintainable, and portable solution with iterators.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Are you saying that there is no execution speed  difference between run-time iterations and compile-time generated code that directly accesses array values?

Comment: Are *you* saying that there is? (Do you know you can write `it[0]`?)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes If you use iterators you must use it in a loop. Loop implies jmp instruction and it hinders processor pipeline. Especialy on moder vectorised architectures.

Comment: @Predrag That's just plain wrong. Do you know you can write `it[0]`?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Got it. I'll measure...

Comment: Seriously: you got some great advice here. Just swallow your prejudices and give it a try. Modern compilers do know when they are iterating over a compile-time constant number of elements, and they are capable of inlining and unrolling that and eliminating the loop overhead. But they will only do that if pays off (you do PGO, right?). If you are doing any sort of heavy floating point computation *per lattice point*, then the lattice loop itself will be **negligible** even if it would not be optimized away (which it likely will).

Answer (score 7):

There is no easier way to do that while keeping your function the same than this:

```
std::array<double, 3> temp{a[1], a[2], a[3]};
f(temp);
```

Instead, make your function take two iterators, and have it work for much more than a `std::array` with 3 elements:

```
template<typename Iter>
void f(Iter first, Iter last);

f(std::next(std::begin(a)), std::end(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a compile-time solution that doesn't use iterators, since you seem to think they'll add overhead:

```
template<size_t N> void f(double*);
...
int main() {
    std::array<double,4> a;
    ...
    f<3>(a.data());
}
```

IMHO this is not better than just passing two iterators though.  If `f` can be inlined the compiler will be able to optimise traversing from `a.begin()` to `a.begin()+3` as well as if you pass it `array<double, 3>` (if you're paying attention you'll noticed the constant `3` is a constant in all cases.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this alternative. Thus your function would accept whatever array you want. It should be defined in a `.h` file

```
template<typename Type> void f(Type &arr)
{
 for (auto it=arr.rbegin(),int i=0;it!=arr.rend();++it,i++)
  {
    if (i < N)//<-- Your last N elements of arr
     std::cout << (*it) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The way to call would be the following:

```
int main()
{
 std::array<double,3> test1;
 f(test1);
}
```

Note: You did not specify how you get the last `N` elements. But there are several ways.

Comment: I don't wont _all_ elements of `test1` to be passed to f().

Comment: Then reduce it before passing it to the function...?

Comment: Example? (Without copying/moving.)

Comment: See edit. Although I would edit the original question with some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Since `std::array` is a standard-layout type (as long as the inner type is, of course), and moreover, layout compatible with a plain old array, the following cast should get what you need.

```
f(reinterpret_cast<std::array<double,3>&>(a));
```

Now, this cast is ugly as hell, so some syntatic sugar is in order:

```
template<size_t N2, typename T, size_t N1>
std::array<T, N2> resize_array(std::array<T,N1> &a, int offset)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<std::array<T,N2>&>(a[offset]);
}
...
f(resize_array<3>(a, 1));
```

If the offset is a compiler constant you could make it also a template parameter, and you could even make the compiler check the range! But that's left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Of course that’s still UB because it violates strict aliasing.

Comment: Is it really layout compatible with an array? Here's the definition of layout-compatible: "If two types T1 and T2 are the same type, then T1 and T2 are layout-compatible types. [ Note: Layout-compatible
enumerations are described in 7.2. Layout-compatible standard-layout structs and standard-layout
unions are described in 9.2. —end note ]". Neither the plain old arrays are not structs, enums, or unions. And, obviously, the arrays are not the same type. (FWIW, I think it's silly that they aren't layout-compatible :S)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Ok, there is no formal definition of layout-compatible arrays, but that's probably because arrays are required to have contiguous memory anyway, so any piece of array should be layout compatible with any other (of layout-compatible types). Now, that `std::array<T,N>` is layout compatible with `T[n]` is not stated explicitly anywhere, that I'm aware of, but I believe that this is the intention of the standard (somewhat like the contiguous requirement of `std::vector` in C++98).

Answer (score -2):

You can try a union:

```
int main() {
    union U {
        std::array<double,4> a;
        struct {
            double dummy;
            std::array<double,3> a;
        } s;
    } u;
    std::array<double,4> &a = u.a;
    std::array<double,3> &a1 = u.s.a;
    ...
    f(a1);
}
```

It should work, but I'm not totally sure about the portability...

Comment: I believe it's technically undefined behaviour, but union tricks are actually quite common it seems.

Comment: @chris: maybe, but IIRC `std::array` of a POD type is also a POD type, and moreover, layout compatible with the equivalent plain old array. Thus, the question would be if my union will be UB even with plain arrays, but I really never learnt all the rules of unions...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's likely to work, but that retrieving any value that wasn't the last set is officially UB.

Comment: @rodrigo I hopped for some clean cast (if there is such ting), but this might do the job. Thanks.

Comment: @chris: But there was an exception to this rule when the common initial sequence of each union member is the same. Now, the initial sequence is not exactly the same... but it is somewhat almost quite similar...

Comment: @rodrigo, You piqued my interest enough to look in the standard, and you're right, as long as they're standard layout types.

Comment: @Predrag: Well, if you really want a cast and feel brave: `reinterpret_cast<std::array<double,3>&>(a[1])`. 8-)

Comment: @rodrigo Thank you! That _is_ what I was hopping for. btw, why do you consider this cast more brave than the enum you originaly offered?

Comment: @Predrag: I don't know, `reinterpret_cast` just lights a red bulb in my head. But on second thought it should be safe... I'm posting another answer, risking more negative votes...